# Swift fetch stripeId from paymentContextDidChange

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I'm simply trying to fetch the payment Id for the selected payment method from the `presentPaymentOptionsViewController` but `selectedPaymentOption` has no `paymentId` or `stripeId` call. How can I fetch it? (When I print out `selectedPaymentOption` it shows me all the data from `STPPaymentMethod` and the `stripeId` which is what I'm trying to get.)

**Presenting Payment Options**

```
var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext?

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("stripe_customers").document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in

            let customerId = snapshot?["customer_id"] as? String ?? ""
            let accountId = snapshot?["account_id"] as? String ?? ""

            let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeAPI(customerId: customerId))
            paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
            paymentContext!.delegate = self
            paymentContext!.hostViewController = self
            paymentContext!.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
        }
    }
```

**PaymentContextDidChange**

```
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
        let selectedPaymentOption = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption
        print(selectedPaymentOption)
    }
```

Comment: `STPPaymentOption` is a `protocol` which you could try to cast it to actual `PaymentMethod` probably. I have not tried it but give ` let selectedPaymentOption = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption as STPPaymentMethodCard ` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to cast the paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption to numerous types, I landed on the following. Casting to STPPaymentMethod at least works for card types.

```
func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    
    if let paymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption as? STPPaymentMethod {
        let paymentMethodId = paymentMethod.stripeId
        let paymentOption = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption
        
        //do what you need to do here...
    }
}
```